# htaccess separate root and sub-directory redirects

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

I feel for the amount of time I have been developing I might know more about .htaccess files but unfortunately do not. The file currently redirects any directory to the root file index.php?url= but I need to add a redirect for anything after /admin/ to go to the admin.php file. I have tried the code below which had zero effect. I'd be most grateful if someone could shed some light on what I might have done wrong.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

Options -MultiViews

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/admin/(.*)$ /admin.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]

RedirectMatch 403 ^/.+\.(log|dat)$
```

Comment: try: `RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)$ /admin.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]`

Comment: Ah what a silly mistake to make, thanks soo much that worked a treat :)